# Is it true that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx}{n}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-distributions

Suppose $f$ is $L^{1}[0,\infty)$ and non-negative, and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$.

Is it true that $lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx}{n}=0$?

I derive this problem from a probability problem where I am asked to compute a limit of an expectation and $f$ is the probability density function. However, I cannot make an estimate for this integral.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: You can rewrite the limit as
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{f(x)}{nx}\mathbb{1}_{[1/n,1]}(x)\text{ d}x}\right)}. $$
Show that
$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{nx}\mathbb{1}_{[1/n,1]}(x)\right|\le|f(x)|$$
for all $x$ and $n$. Then apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: isn't there an issue with the last bound? If you take $x=1/2$, $f(x)/x=2f(x)\geq f(x)$